# how to focus on next input field with press enter key in angular4

Tags: angular

how to focus next input field with enter keypress in angular4

```
  import { Component, OnInit,ElementRef,ViewChild,Directive,Renderer,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'cbody',
    templateUrl: './cbody.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./cbody.component.css']
  })  
  export class CbodyComponent  implements  OnInit, AfterViewInit  {

    constructor(public renderer: Renderer,private el:ElementRef) {}

    @ViewChild('ft01') infocus: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit(){};

    ngAfterViewInit() {
          this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
          this.infocus.nativeElement, 'focus');                     
    }

    keytab(event:any){      
          console.log(event.keyCode );  
          console.log(this.dataloops );     
    }

   dataloops=[
    { "name":"csdn" , "url":"www.runoob.com" }, 
    { "name":"google" , "url":"www.google.com" }, 
    { "name":"ifeng" , "url":"www.weibo.com" }
   ];

  }

 <p>
   cbody works!
 </p>


 <div>
 <ul *ngFor="let dataloop of dataloops">
    <li  >{{dataloop.name}}<input type="text" name="intext" [(ngModel)]="dataloop.url" #ft01 (keyup.enter)="keytab($event)"/></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you are using the *ngFor in a wrong way, it repeats the element which is placed on.
you need to set the *ngFor on the li element.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let dataloop of dataloops">
       {{dataloop.name}}
        <input type="text" name="intext" 
        [(ngModel)]="dataloop.url" #ft01 (keyup.enter)="keytab($event)"/>  
    </li>
 </ul>
```

now update the .ts file as following

```
keytab(event){
    let element = event.srcElement.nextElementSibling; // get the sibling element

    if(element == null)  // check if its null
        return;
    else
        element.focus();   // focus if not null
}
```

this code should work fine.

Comment: thanks your answer.i do know  event.srcElement can got element.id and value,tagName etc, i just want know when i key press enter in first input field ,how to move focus on second input field, i use like element.nextSibling.focus but could not work.

Comment: if this element was the last one, then nextElementSibling of it will be null.

Comment: i know its need press enter key  in first or second field , not in last input field ,but   element = event.srcElement.nextElementSibling;    console.log(element);  the result is null , but i can   get like event.srcElement.value.

Comment: i know how to work ,thanks a lot for your help , so its need to return to li ,then next to nextElementSibling.childNodes[1] , let element = event.srcElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.childNodes[1], and element.focus();

Answer (score 1):

you have to  use the renderer to access next sibling element; using renderer2 :
inject renderer2 in the constructor and then:

```
this.renderer2.parentNode(this.el.nativeElement).focus();
```